# PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet get cell column index as integer

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

How can I get cell column index as integer? I have searched the documentation but I didn't found anything.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

please see [Accessing cells](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/)

```
$ColumnIndex = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($Column);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a cell then you can use the public functions - getColumn(), getRow(), getCoordinate()

Go read the source in [Github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/develop/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Cell.php)

Comment: This is a first step, which I think OP had found. But getColumn and getCoordinate return strings. OP asked for integer values :)

Comment: Once you got the column string coordinate, use `Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($column)` to get the column index [1-n]